# Is there a way to highlight particular cells only when there is partial code know

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

Conditional formatting to highlight cells when a particular number is shown more than once.

I have a set of core numbers that are fixed in the order numbers, but I want to highlight only those that have the core numbers shown more than once

Here are a few core numbers and how they are shown in the order numbers

```
Sample Order number
PMGAG5216GC
PMG005216GC
PMGVV5237GCB
PMG005237GCB
```

Core number that is common in that

```
5216
5327
```

They should be highlighted if they have that core number in it, else leave is with no color. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the formatting option of "format only unique values or duplicate values" in a different row, where you extract the core values. Using it in the same column as your order number. so extracting in a new column is a viable solution. Because you have to check for duplicates in the core value, use COUNTIF(range, value) formula.
[image: Screenshot of Conditional formatting formula]

Comment: sure, will try that.

Comment: I have created a column B which pulls all the core numbers and using the conditional formatting I highlighted the duplicates. But my question is how will I highlight column A rows based on the duplicates identified in column B.

Comment: Now select the A rows you want to put your highlights on, goto highlight with a formula, then type in the formula box: =countif(<range>,<cell>)>1 for example, to highlight cells a1:a10, from dublicate values in b1:b10, goto conditional formatting after selecting a1:a10 and in formula write: =countif(b$1:b$10,b1)>1

Comment: I have edited the answer to include screenshot of the formula and data. If it doesn't work that way, I have a working excel file in my github with same username. check there.